# c# convert string to date type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got this string:

```
string date = "Sun, 17 Mar 2013 12:40:23 +0000";
```

And trying to convert to a date type but I keep getting a not in correct format error when I try the convert.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

And then trying to get it into these formats:

```
dt.ToString("dd")
dt.ToString("MMMM")
dt.ToString("yyyy")
```

Comment: I get no exceptions when running that code, and it works as expected. What locale are you in?

Comment: He probably has different culture settings on his OS, that represent dates differently. Convert uses them and fails to parse.

Comment: when exactly have you got error? this same code worked for me? try making debug statement once.

Comment: Yup it was the CultureInfo needed. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) for the conversion.

Try the following code:

```
var date = "Sun, 17 Mar 2013 12:40:23 +0000";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd"));
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MMMM"));
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy"));
```

Output:

```
17
March
2013
```

Comment: +1 for using InvariantCulture. I suspect this is what's needed to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Try `DateTime.TryParse()` or `DateTime.Parse()`

Comment: His code works fine with what he posted though, so no idea what the problem actually is... I think it's a locale problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) instead.

`var dt = DateTime.Parse(date);`

I would also recommend that you Parse the date using [DateTime.TryParse](http://DateTime.TryParse) to make sure that the date is always in a valid format.

```
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("dd"));
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("MMMM"));
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("yyyy"));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error parsing date.");
}
```

If you are still experiencing issues you may need to provide DateTime with a [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). This allows you to specify the exact Culture used by the parser, to ensure that the computer region settings doesn't cause any issues.

```
DateTime.Parse(date, new CultureInfo("en-US"));     // Specific culture
DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // Culture-insensitive

// Culture-insensitive TryParse
if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out result, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) 
{...}
```

The normal DateTime uses the culture set by your Operating System.

Comment: Yup needed cultureinfo, OS was different on live server than local dev machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTime.Parse` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which ignores your current culture, hence avoids possible localization issues.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is similar to the english culture and works with your string.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/rUszoQ)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) method? If you scroll down, you will notice that the last sample actually is "Fri, 15 May 2009 20:10:57 GMT", similar to your request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) method like;

```
string date = "Sun, 17 Mar 2013 12:40:23 +0000";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd"));
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MMMM"));
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy"));
```

Output will be;

```
17
March
2013
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/GzAbBg).

Comment: -1: The `Convert.ToDateTime` part is not good, not necessary, and downright confusing.

Comment: I think you've actually made this *worse*. Choose `ParseExact` or `TryParse` (or, you know, combine them - `TryParseExact`) and stick with it. Don't do both, it's just confusing

Comment: I think this is acceptable, but I don't see why not just skip the additional `DateTime.Parse` and add `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to the TryParse? It serves no purposes besides possibly using a few extra cpu cycles, and could trigger an unwanted `FormatException`.

Comment: It doesnt matter which way is *better*, just that you don't do *both* unnecessarily. -1 removed.

Answer (score 0):

Well..If you need the result in numeric format,try as shown below

```
 string date = "Sun, 17 Mar 2013 12:40:23 +0000";
 DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
 var day = dt.Day;
 var month = dt.Month;
 var year = dt.Year;
 var time = dt.ToShortTimeString();
 var hour = dt.Hour;
 var minute = dt.Minute;
 var second = dt.Second;
```

The Variables will return the exact numerical form.
NB: Hour will be depicted as 24 hour format

Answer (score 0):

public string dateConvertion(string da)
    {
        string sDate = da;
        sDate = sDate.Replace("-", "/");
        sDate = sDate.Replace(".", "/");

```
    string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    DateTime dDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(sDate, out dDate))
    {

        //if (DateTime.TryParseExact(sDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDate))
        //{

        sDate = dDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        sDate = sDate.Replace("-", "/");
        sDate = sDate.Replace(".", "/");

    }
    return sDate;
}
```